# Configuring resiliency settings Entity Framework 6.02

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to configure resiliency settings for EF6.02. I have an application which in one point of execution writes a log entry to database. The application is not depending on the SQL-server so if the server does not respond, I want the application to abandon the INSERT query (through SaveChanges of the DbContext) and continue execution immediately.

Using default settings, the debug log outputs ten

> "A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

After the ten tries, it throws an exception and my code continues. But I want just one try and for example 2 s command timeout. According to documentation on MSDN, default resiliency method for SQL server is:

> **DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy**: *this is an internal execution strategy that is used by default. This strategy does not retry at all, however, it will wrap any exceptions that could be transient to inform users that they might want to enable connection resiliency.*

As the documentation mentions, this strategy does not retry at all. But still I have ten retries. I have tried to create a class which inherits DbConfiguration but I have not found any documentation on how to change this.

Can anyone help me reduce the number of retries?

UPDATE: Below is code based on suggestions

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;

namespace MyDbLayer
{
    public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public MyConfiguration ()
        {

          this.SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => SuspendExecutionStrategy
          ? (IDbExecutionStrategy)new DefaultExecutionStrategy()
          : new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());
        }

        public static bool SuspendExecutionStrategy
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool?)CallContext.LogicalGetData("SuspendExecutionStrategy") ?? false;
            }
            set
            {
                CallContext.LogicalSetData("SuspendExecutionStrategy", value);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

And code writing to SQL

```
try
    {
        using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities ())
        {
            Log logEntry = new Log();
            logEntry.TS = DateTime.Now;

            MyConfiguration.SuspendExecutionStrategy = true;
            context.Log.Add(logEntry);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Warn("Connection error with database server.", ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        //Enable retries again...
        MyConfiguration.SuspendExecutionStrategy = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try [**execution strategy suspension**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn307226#transactions_workarounds)?

Your own DB configuration would be like this one:

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration 
{ 
    public MyConfiguration() 
    { 
        this.SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => SuspendExecutionStrategy 
          ? (IDbExecutionStrategy)new DefaultExecutionStrategy() 
          : new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy()); 
    } 

    public static bool SuspendExecutionStrategy 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return (bool?)CallContext.LogicalGetData("SuspendExecutionStrategy") ?? false; 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            CallContext.LogicalSetData("SuspendExecutionStrategy", value); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

then you may define non-retriable command like this:

```
public static void ExecWithoutRetry(System.Action action)
{
    var restoreExecutionStrategyState = EbgDbConfiguration.SuspendExecutionStrategy;
    try
    {
        MyConfiguration.SuspendExecutionStrategy = true;
        action();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // ignore any exception if we want to
    }
    finally
    {
        MyConfiguration.SuspendExecutionStrategy = restoreExecutionStrategyState;
    }
}
```

and finally your regular DB code with retriable and non-retriable commands may look like this:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    ExecWithoutRetry(() => db.WriteEvent("My event without retries"));
    db.DoAnyOperationWithRetryStrategy();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is all this code needed to decrease the number of connection retries in Entity Framework 6?? (!)

Comment: @ElToro, maybe I misunderstood your question. If you want to disable retries for all SQL commands then just change `MyConfiguration` constructor like this: `this.SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new DefaultExecutionStrategy()`. My solution disables retries only for a specific part of you code writing events.

Comment: No you were right from the beginning. I was just stunned over how complicated (even though your beautiful code). I though an easier way would be possible. For example: "context.Connection.NumberOfExecutionRetries = 0". But many thanks!

Comment: I've wrapped non-retriable command with `ExecWithoutRetry()` method for clearer logic flow. I'm doing like this myself and unfortunately I was unable to find another shorter way of combining retriable and non-retriable commands.

Comment: Strange, I just tried your original code and still multiple retries are executed...

Comment: I can see using the debugger that the constructor is called upon start and the property SuspendExecutionStrategy is called when I change the property but still it retries 10 times...

Comment: @ElToro, I would like to see your actual code in order to be able to help you.

Comment: Please see my updated post. The DbConfiguration is in the same assembly as the Entity Data Model. I´m not using Code-First.

Comment: @ElToro, I suppose that something is wrong with your `Log` entity (maybe some required field is not initialized?). I've checked exactly your code but could not reproduce your issue. What message outputs your `logger.Warn("Connection error with database server.", ex)`?

Comment: when i start the server eveything works as expected so it´s nothing with the entity. The error is the regular "no server in the other end" exception (I´m not at the office right now sorry).

Comment: @ElToro, I tried stopping SQL Server and DB but only 1 connection try occured in both cases (even when retries are ON). Also you might notice already that even with retries policy ON there is only a narrow list of errors which cause retries: `This execution strategy will retry the operation on TimeoutException and SqlException if the Errors contains any of the following error numbers: 40613, 40501, 40197, 10929, 10928, 10060, 10054, 10053, 233, 64 and 20`. So probably ten events in your log are written outside of DB operation.

Comment: I will look at this when I get back to the office. The events in are not in my log, they are an in the Visual Studio debug log. So I do not receive them to my application but the SaveChanges() does not return until those ten retries have been performed..

Comment: I have tested this again. According to debug output I see 11

"A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

After the 11 retries, I receive one exception in my application:

{System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904). bla bla bla (Error 40) at "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()"

So I receive only one exception, but since my connection timeout is set to 1 second, I have to wait 11 seconds for that exception...

Comment: I also tried this:

DefaultExecutionStrategy strategy = new DefaultExecutionStrategy();
strategy.Execute(() => context.SaveChanges());

But it also retries 10 times which makes it take > 10 seconds before the exception is thrown. 

I fear that this has nothing to do with Resiliency settings but with something with the System.Data.SqlClient...

Comment: @ElToro, I see that `EntityConnection.Open()` implementation also uses execution strategy, so you have to call `MyConfiguration.SuspendExecutionStrategy = true` before `new MyEntities()`. If it does not work then you may try also `new DefaultExecutionStrategy().Execute(() => {context = new MyEntities();})` or even open connection explicitly before calling `context.SaveChanges()`

Comment: Thanks for all your help, how can I "repay" you without marking your solution as the answer? Your solution was actually the solution to my question but not the solution to my problem :-)

Comment: I could not because my account is new and I have no reputation. I marked your solution as answer instead...

Comment: @ElToro, thank you for such a generous reward! Sorry that my answer was not what is finnaly helped you to solve the problem!

Answer (score -1):

I found it. I just needed to add "Connection Timeout=X" where X is seconds to the connection string and everything worked without needing to modify ExecutionStrategies etc.

Adding this before executing query solved it

```
contextInstance.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString + ";Connection Timeout=2;";
```

Comment: You shouldn't append to the connection string in code. Change the connection string itself instead. Your code goes against the whole concept of dynamic configuration and makes configuring your app non-intuitive.

Comment: Since I´m using different timeouts for different queries, I can´t see how that can be performed my changing the connection string in the config file.